# Find the average windspeed in January for each location

Tags: pandas-groupby

find mean of each location in the January month from 1968-1672

watch data for clear understanding:
https://github.com/prataplyf/Wind-DateTime/blob/master/wind_data.csv

````
year = wind.index.year.unique()
year

month = wind[(wind.index.year==wind.index.year.unique())]
month.mean()```






get 'mean()' of each location only Jan data
Output format
         RPT   VAL  ...... ...... ..... ...... .... ....BEL MAL
1961-1 
1962-1
1963-1
.
.
.
.
.
1672-1
````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate the min, max and mean windspeeds and standard deviations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57339524/calculate-the-min-max-and-mean-windspeeds-and-standard-deviations)

Answer (score 1):

Data.loc[(Data['Date'].dt.month==1)].mean()

try this