# Calculate the min, max and mean windspeeds and standard deviations

Tags: pandas

Calculate the min, max and mean windspeeds and standard deviations of the windspeeds 
 **:** across all locations for each week (assume that the first week starts on January 2 1961) for the first 52 weeks.

get data
**https://github.com/prataplyf/Wind-DateTime/blob/master/wind_data.csv**

not understad how to solve

weekly average of each location

```
          RTP    VAL   ....... . ..... ..  .. . . .. . . .. ... BEL   MAL
1961-1-1
1961-1-8
1961-1-15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Load the data:

```
df = pd.read_csv('wind_data.csv')
```

## Convert `date` to `datetime` and set as the index

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.set_index('date', drop=True, inplace=True)
```

## Create a `DateFrame` for 1961

```
df_1961 = df[df.index < pd.to_datetime('1962-01-01')]
```

## Resample for statistical calculations

```
df_1961.resample('W').mean()
df_1961.resample('W').min()
df_1961.resample('W').max()
df_1961.resample('W').std()
```

## Plot the data for 1961:

```
fix, axes = plt.subplots(12, 1, figsize=(15, 60), sharex=True)
for name, ax in zip(df_1961.columns, axes):
    ax.plot(df_1961[name], label='Daily')
    ax.plot(df_1961_mean[name], label='Weekly Mean Resample')
    ax.plot(df_1961_min[name], label='Weekly Min')
    ax.plot(df_1961_max[name], label='Weekly Max')
    ax.set_title(name)
    ax.legend()
```